# Inkscape : Exporting SVG to different icon sizes

Tags: inkscape, svg, icon, resize

What if we start working an icon with 32x32 template and need more icon sizes from the base art. Like, I made a camera icon using 32x32 template and is in need of 48x48, 64x64 etc variants in SVG format. Can we do this resize from the base art window ? If yes, please tell me how.

Comment: You do realize that SVGs don't have pixels, right?   You can scale an SVG to any size you want.

Comment: Yes. I am trying to start working with a single icon size and then derive different icon sizes from it, without leaving the base windows. Is it possible @BillyKerr ? Thanks.

Comment: Didn't I already say "you can"?

Comment: I still don't know how. Say, I have already drawn the icon and now I want variants in 64 ,128, 512 etc. I want to save in different sized template, not scale. :)

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it's not clear.  You say you want to change the icon size, then you say you don't want to scale it?  This doesn't make sense.  We are just going round in circles here.

Comment: I asked about " exporting " to different icon sizes, not changing. Please check the title. The intention is very clear.

Answer (score 4):

Duplicate the icon and change the size with[image] the dialogue box make sure the measurement is set to px

Comment: Thanks @Junme . I tried the same and used CTRL + Shift + R. The doc got resized as well.